# Setting struct pointer

Tags: c

I'm having a problem figuring out how to initiate an array of struct pointers.
What i bascially want to do is loop through the array of struct pointers and for each pointer i want to do some work.

The code for the structure:

```
typedef double Align;
union header {
    struct {
        union header * p, *prev;
        unsigned size;
    } s;
    Align x;
};

typedef union header Header;
```

and the code that i can't get to work is following:

```
Header * freelist[NRQUICKLISTS]; /* Listan med  */

void init() { /* call this once in the beginning */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NRQUICKLISTS-1; i++) {
        freelist[i]->s.p = freelist[i]; /* <-- this line cause Segmentation fault */
        freelist[i]->s.size = 0;
    }
    freelist[i] = &base;
    freelist[i]->s.p = freep = &base; /* cirkulär lista */
    freelist[i]->s.size = 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using the elements of the array as pointers to objects without having allocated any memory for the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the pointers before you can use them:

```
for (i = 0; i < NRQUICKLISTS-1; i++) {
    freelist[i] = new Header;
    freelist[i]->s.p = freelist[i]; /* <-- this line cause Segmentation fault */
    freelist[i]->s.size = 0;
}
```

Also, I suggest you do it the C++ way - which is using `std:vector` instead of an array.

Edit:

For C, use malloc:

```
for (i = 0; i < NRQUICKLISTS-1; i++) {
    freelist[i] = malloc(sizeof(Header));
    freelist[i]->s.p = freelist[i]; /* <-- this line cause Segmentation fault */
    freelist[i]->s.size = 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use new in C, you can in C++. The question was tagged C++ when I posted the answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: its tagging is messed up and changing a lot, but from the coding you can see its obviously pure C.

Comment: @Dani: Which part tells you it's C and not C++? You can use malloc in C++, also union and struct. I think only the op can answer that. Maybe he wants C++ and we should correct his syntax, right?

Comment: Its pure C, tagging it as c++ was a mistake, sry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate each pointer:

```
for (i = 0; i < NRQUICKLISTS-1; i++)
{
    freelist[i] = malloc(sizeof(Header));
    freelist[i]->s.p = freelist[i];
    freelist[i]->s.size = 0;
}
```

Or alternatively use contiguous storage:

```
Header freelist[NRQUICKLISTS];

for (i = 0; i < NRQUICKLISTS-1; i++)
{
    freelist[i].s.p = freelist + i;
    freelist[i].s.size = 0;
}
```